# Why is Java AWSKMS client decryption so much slower than Python boto3?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

In my Java lambda, during cold start I want to decrypt passwords from environment variables. I'm using the AWSKMS client to decrypt a string (following examples from [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/programming-top.html?shortFooter=true)), and I find it takes up to 2 seconds the first time I do this. In contrast, I have some code in python using boto3 which is doing the same thing and it runs in under 100ms. So clearly there's something wrong with my Java code. Here is the Java code with comments showing the 2 calls that together add up to nearly 2 seconds:

```
ByteBuffer ciphertextBlob = ByteBuffer.wrap(Base64.getDecoder().decode(encrValue));
DecryptRequest req = new DecryptRequest().withCiphertextBlob(ciphertextBlob);
AWSKMS kmsClient = AWSKMSClientBuilder.defaultClient();     // This call takes 800+ ms
ByteBuffer plainText = kmsClient.decrypt(req).getPlaintext();   // This call takes 900+ ms
String plainTextStr = StringUtils.stripToNull(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.decode(plainText).toString());
```

And here's the equivalent python code:

```
plainTextStr = boto3.client('kms').decrypt(CiphertextBlob=b64decode(encrValue))['Plaintext'].decode()
```

Clearly I'm doing something wrong in the Java code, but I can't find a simpler example of how to do it in Java.

Comment: not really an answer but have seen the AWSKMS declared as private static final on the class it is needed so only initialised once. eg     private static final AWSKMS kmsClient = AWSKMSClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_2).build();   I have the same issue with the decrypt call also taking too long from my expectations.  we use it as a rotating key every hour so  seconds in an hour is not bad, but not perfect for our use

Comment: Thanks user2168435 we are using static too so we are only doing decryption on cold start. I opened a ticket with AWS about this, and their response was that there's nothing wrong with their KMS client, the problem is just that Java libraries take longer to load due to size. I'm not buying that since their other APIs do not have such big cold start delays.